# OpenSSH sftp 'put' with a trailing slash on the source folder or not?

Tags: centos, sftp, openssh

I need to copy a directory (`/local_backups`) containing database backups from my CentOS server to an offsite SFTP server. But I am uncertain about something:
Should I run the command with a trailing slash after the source folder or not?

Should it be A or B?

A. `sftp> put -r /local_backups`

B. `sftp> put -r /local_backups/`

I have searched many forums and cannot find anything specific to `sftp` commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not matter. In both cases, it behaves as if the path was ending with the slash:

```
sftp> put -r /local_backups
Uploading /local_backups/ to /
Entering /local_backups/
```

```
sftp> put -r /local_backups/
Uploading /local_backups/ to /
Entering /local_backups/
```